# I am stuck on a very particular word that means smart and curious

Tags: single-word-requests

It's on the tip of my tongue. The great thing about this word is that there's a connotation that a person it describes is not just smart or curious, but that they find a childlike joy in learning.

This word is paired with the word "intellectually", as in "intellectually curious." But when it's on its own, it's more likely to be describing someone who's cheeky or sassy, particularly a child. But in that usage, there's the connotation that their cheekiness or sassiness belies gifted intelligence.

I am pretty sure it starts with a p, or even maybe 'pro,' but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Is it precocious?

Comment: Precocious is only used when talking about children (possibly including teenagers). So, if the word can also be used when referring to an adult then precocious isn't a good fit.

Comment: Precocious! That's it!

But damn! I didn't realise it only applied to children. I looked it up, it's true though. I'll have to rethink my use of the word. So you've helped me more than I expected. 

Thank you.

Comment: Answers, even tentative answers, should go in the answer box. @Michael Could you write your own answer? (Be sure to include a supporting reference now you know what to look up: I know you're new here, but it's all good to do.)

Comment: @KillingTime: Unless it's precocious dementia.

Comment: *perspicacious* is right up there too

Comment: @TimR: It means early in development or occurrence. So strictly speaking, it doesn't always have to refer to a child. If I'm 40, but I think like a 70-year old, then I have a precocious mind. But that would be a very strange usage of the word, as that would not be nearly as remarkable as a child with a precocious intellect. 

So precocious dementia would just be early onset dementia, and that would totally be consistent with the meaning of the word. You can also have precocious puberty.

Comment: @MichaelAtkins-Prescott Of course. It was a joke.

Answer (score 1):

Precocious. The answer was precocious. Didn't quite have the right definition though, so it's no good for my purposes. Still, 'precocious' was the word I was thinking of.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precocious

Comment: Yes, but bear in mind that in BrE at least, precocious is used as a term of abuse, synonymous with brat.

Comment: I think it's a bit strong to say it's a term of abuse, although it often has negative connotations. (It can also refer specifically to sexual precocity, which is another thing entirely.)

Comment: This word literally means “ahead of [their] age” (from Latin, _praecox_ meaning “matured early”). You can use it to talk about children, but it would be very strange to see it applied to an adult.

Comment: @Chenmunka I believe 'precocious' isn't abusive by itself; only in combination, typically as 'precocious brat…'. The more since KrisW has corrected my life-long misapprehension from 'became conscious…' to 'matured…' early, I don't understand how 'sexual precocity' is linguistically different, as opposed to socially.

I don't think precociousness involves curiosity, cheek or sass except in queries or comments supposedly beyond the speaker's years; clearly denied by 'particularly a child…'.

Answer (score 0):

Another word that is closer to intelligently curious is

**inquisitive** (adj.)

> Given to inquiry, questioning, or research; of an inquiring turn of
> mind; desirous of or eager for knowledge; curious. (Of persons, their
> dispositions, actions, etc.)
> [OED online]

---

> This conception could go both with a Christian and a romantic reading,
> but what upsets the picture is Quennell's reference to them as being
> '**intellectually inquisitive**'.
> [Axel Andersson; *A Hero for the
> Atomic Age: Thor Heyerdahl and the Kon-Tiki Expedition*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JrhPH-9mnd8C&pg=PA109&dq=%22intellectually%20inquisitive%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih1IaV4LKDAxXOF1kFHY-oBiEQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22intellectually%20inquisitive%22&f=false)

> [Will] Hall is a skillful and highly motivated organizer and a smart,
> **intellectually inquisitive** activist, but judging from his writings and
> his interviews as the moderator of *Madnes Radio*, my sense is that he
> does not believe his role as a spokesperson for Mad Pride is to
> provide intellectual leadership for Mad Pride activists.
> [Seth Farber;
> *The Spiritual Gift of Madness*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MFwoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&dq=%22intellectually%20inquisitive%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih1IaV4LKDAxXOF1kFHY-oBiEQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22intellectually%20inquisitive%22&f=false) (2012)

> However, Francis's older teacher, Mrs. Gordon, called him inpertinent
> and too **inquisitive, sassy,** and sometimes argumentative when he
> would stubbornly stay to an idea.
> [C.A. Portnellus; *Things of the
> Earth*](https://books.google.com/books?id=uWBADAAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&dq=inquisitive%20sassy%20child&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiywK-Q47KDAxWVFFkFHcA2BU0Q6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=inquisitive%20sassy%20child&f=false) (2016)

> Nikitah was very **inquisitive** as a child. She was smart and
> **sassy**.
> [Winifred Howard; *How Do You Let Go*](https://books.google.com/books?id=32_3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT73&dq=inquisitive%20sassy%20child&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiywK-Q47KDAxWVFFkFHcA2BU0Q6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=inquisitive%20sassy%20child&f=false) (2020)

> But Teddy was not nervous, not a sign of it. He was thoroughly
> confiding and **cheeky and inquisitive**. There was hardly a latch on
> the farm that he could not undo, and if it were secured by a string he
> would set to work to undo the knot!
> [Olive Hockin; *Two Girls on the
> Land*](https://books.google.com/books?id=d5bUAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22cheeky%20and%20inquisitive%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVh7LO5LKDAxWFVjUKHRA3BZoQ6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=%22cheeky%20and%20inquisitive%22&f=false) (1918)